# What is the proper way of using bridge endpointConfigurer?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm looking for a component about how to connect different integration flows by root flow. I've seen [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-integration-java-dsl) tutorial(see 5.2. Bridge); it has one main root flow, then two different flows. I've tried this in my application, but it didn't work without putting *PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER*. Gives an error: *no default poller is available within the context.* When I add *PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER*, times in bridge endpointConfigurer is not working as expected. Probably, It clashes by default poller configuration.

In short, how can I connect two different flows by one main root? But, different flows has to work in different times.

I don't know that I'm using right component or not, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

In addition, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936422/how-to-use-pollerspec-in-integrationflowdefinition-bridge-properly-with-poller) question which is kind a similar. It could help to understand my question.

**UPDATE**

```
    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller() {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 10).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReader() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(sourceDirectory())
                .split()
                .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
                        .subscribe("fileWriter"))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
                        .subscribe("anotherFileWriter"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileWriter() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("fileWriter")
                .bridge(e -> e.poller(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5))
                .handle()
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow anotherFileWriter() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("anotherFileWriter")
                .bridge(e -> e.poller(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5))
                .handle()
                .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show your code when asking questions like this.

It's not entirely clear what you mean by

> In short, how can I connect two different flows by one main root?

If they both consume from the same pollable channel each message will only go to one or the other flow.

To specifically answer your question, the example you pointed to shows how to configure a specific poller on the endpoint...

```
>.bridge(e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 20)))
```

You only need a default poller if you omit the poller on the endpoint.

Comment: As you mentioned, when I add default poller it works fine, but times that I mentioned in bridge doesn't work properly. I've checked the log messages, application depends on default poller. That is my problem. I thought, I'm tried to use wrong component for unrelated issue. Basically, I want to know "how bridge poller behaves with default poller?" e.i. If default poller's period is 5 min and poller in bridge is 1 min, what should I expect? Also, I've updated the question with implementation.

Comment: 1. Your 2 subscriptions should be on the same `publishSubscribeChannel`; 2. When you explicitly provide pollers like that, the default poller is not used at all. 3. Your channels are direct channels, so they will be called immediately on the main poller thread; you need change them to queue channels to use a poller there.